# How to return a lambda function containing a function capture? (C++)

Tags: c++, function, lambda, return, function-pointers

I am new to this Lambda function in C++. I wanted to return a lambda function containing a function capture like this:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

//typedef void(*func1)();

auto func(void(*func2)())
{
    return [&func2](){cout<<"hello world 1"<<endl;func2();};
}

void func2()
{
    cout<<"hello world 2"<<endl;
}


int main()
{

    func(func2)();


    return 0;
}
```

But this snippet, upon execution, exits with a non zero number. Also, the func2() is not executed.
Please let me know how to fix this and also tell me the actual format of that auto portion.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lambda that you return from `func`:

```
return [&func2]() {
  // ...
};
```

is capturing `func2` by reference. Since `func2` is local to `func`, this reference is dangling when you return from `func`. So in `main`, you get undefined behavior when `func2` is called in the body of the lambda.

You can fix this by making the lambda capture `func2` by copy:

```
return [func2]() {
  // ...
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/enqKMv).

Comment: Thank you very much. But what about the auto portion? What is the exact format of that portion? And one more thing. Why does it become dangling when I pass func2 by reference?

Comment: @SayanAcharya I'm not sure what you mean. There's no `auto` anywhere.

Comment: in the definition of func i set the return type to auto. I was talking about that one.

Comment: @SayanAcharya Oops, I see. That means the return type of `func` is whatever the type of the return statement is. In this case, that would be the type of the lambda expression.

Comment: so will it be [func2](){}?
and also why does that func2 become dangling? could not understand the reason?\

Comment: @SayanAcharya The return *type* would be the type of *[func2](){ ...}`.

Comment: @SayanAcharya Look up dangling pointers/references. There are a number of resources on this topic that should be helpful.

Comment: putting  *[func2](){ ...} or *[func2](){ }  does not compile. @cigien.

Comment: @SayanAcharya True. What are you trying to achieve with that? Also, that appears to be a different question, so you might want to ask a separate question about that.

Comment: Just was learning about lambdas and function pointers but could not find anywhere how to implement this. So asked.

Comment: The problem is that the type of a lambda is anonymous -- it does not have a name.  You could use `std::function<void()>` as the return type, but that is not the same type, just a type that it can be converted to implicitly.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. Got it now.