# How to capture a function in C++ lambda

Tags: c++

I'm wondering how I can pass a function in the capture list. My code snippet is shown below. It aborts with `error: capture of non-variable ‘bool isVowel(char)’`.

Why does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64650841/how-to-return-a-lambda-function-containing-a-function-capture-c) similar posted solution with a function pointer work?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

bool isVowel(char c){
  string myVowels{"aeiouäöü"};
  set<char> vowels(myVowels.begin(), myVowels.end());
  return (vowels.find(c) != vowels.end());
}

int main(){
  list<char> myCha{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'};
  int cha[]= {'A', 'B', 'C'};
  // it doesn't work
  auto iter = adjacent_find(myCha.begin(), myCha.end(),
                           [isVowel](char a, char b){ return isVowel(a) == isVowel(b); 
});
  if (iter != myCha.end()) cout << *iter;
    
}
```

Comment: `&isVowel`? Note the `&`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? you do not need to capture a function - it is a global object accessible anyway.

Comment: Why do you think there's a need to capture the function? Just use an empty capture list.

Comment: You don't need to capture it. It's globally available. Captures are for things that would otherwise go out of scope.

Comment: Yes, it's a global function here. This is not a good example. I would like to ask about the general process how to capture a function.

Comment: "how to capture a function" means about the same as "how to fly a car". This does not compute. What does "capture a function" mean to you? What is it supposed to accomplish, that wouldn't otherwise happen without this capture?

Comment: By "capture a function," I mean that I would like to pass a function to the body so that this function can be called inside the body. @SamVarshavchik

Comment: It _might_ make sense if the function you capture depends on a condition.

Comment: @Willi Have you tried to call it without capture?

Comment: @lorro I tried with [&isVowel] and [&isVowel], and both failed.

Comment: You might be surprised to learn that you do not need to capture any function in order to call it from a lambda. Just call it.

Comment: @Willi what I mean, with no capture at all.

Comment: I mean you could do `[f = &isVowel] (...) { return f(a) == f(b); }` but that imho makes the code just harder to understand. If you've got a function pointer or `std::function<...>` object  already this may be a different thing or if you were writing a template function, but in this case you don't.

Comment: @fabian Maybe delete the link or move the link to the top. I just would like to show a similar posted solution that works, and I didn't realize the function point is different to a function in C++ at that moment.

Comment: "I didn't realize the function point is different to a function in C++ at that moment." looks like you did not understand the answer. Problem is not difference btw function pointer and function, but difference btw local variable and global object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does this similar snippet work?

Because in that snippet:

```
auto func(void(*func2)())
{
    return [&func2](){cout<<"hello world 1"<<endl;func2();};
}
```

`func2` is a local variable with type pointer to a function. In your case you are trying to capture a function itself which is not allowed:

> The identifier in any capture without an initializer (other than the
> this-capture) is looked up using usual unqualified name lookup in the
> reaching scope of the lambda. **The result of the lookup must be a
> variable with automatic storage duration declared in the reaching
> scope**, or a structured binding whose corresponding variable satisfies
> such requirements (since C++20). The entity is explicitly captured.

from [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Lambda_capture) (emphasis is mine).  Function name is definitely not a variable with automatic storage duration.

Not clear why are you trying to capture this function, as it would work without any capture and it does not make any sense (unlike question you point to, where OP wanted to use different function in different case hence he/she captured the pointer).

PS according to your comment you did not understand main reason of error here. Consider these 2 snippets:

```
int i = 0;

int main() {
    auto f = [i]() {}; // illegal, should fail to compile
}
```

vs this:

```
int main() {
    int i = 0;
    auto f = [i]() {}; // should compile fine
}
```

First snippet is incorrect (though gcc may compile it with warning), second one is just fine.

Comment: Why &func2: `return [&func2](){ ...`    and not func2:   `return [func2](){ ... ` ?

Comment: @CGi03 that is what provided in the question linked from this one. That is not proper way in that case, but unrelated to issue here

Comment: @CGi03 that code has a mistake in it, that's why it was on Stack Overflow :)